# Autre sens du mot « orthogonal » pour désigner deux avis différents ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

Dans un post sur la communauté [English language and usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), un membre demande quel mot peut être utilisé pour décrire le fait qu'une compétence n'est d'aucune aide dans un autre domaine.

C'est le mot anglais « orthogonal » qui a été accepté. Voir ici [la réponse](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400570).

Dans cette réponse il dit :

> Use this word in everyday conversation when you want to say "I'm not
>   fighting you. Our opinions differ, that's all. They're orthogonal."

Je me demandais si on pouvait également utiliser le mot français « orthogonal » pour désigner deux avis différents, afin de ne pas froisser l'interlocuteur quand il n'est pas d'accord avec ce que l'on dit.

Exemple :

> Bien que nous ne soyons pas d'accord, je ne suis pas en conflit avec
>   toi. Nos avis sont seulement orthogonaux.

Comment: En conservant le registre de la géométrie, mais en insistant (au contraire de ce que tu veux véhiculer, si j'ai bien compris) sur l'incompatibilité de points de vue, on aurait eu l'expression *avoir des avis diamétralement opposés*. Dommage...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En français, **[Orthogonal](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/orthogonal)** a uniquement un sens géométrique.

> • Droites orthogonales, plans orthogonaux
>
> • Courbes, ellipses, hyperboles orthogonales
>
> • Projection orthogonale

Pour illustrer l'exemple donné dans la question, le verbe **[Diverger](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/diverger)** me semble plus approprié

> Être en désaccord, en opposition. Sur beaucoup de problèmes (...) les politiques britannique et française ont divergé (De Gaulle, Mém. guerre,1959, p. 560)

Ce qui donnerait la phrase suivante :

> Bien que nous ne soyons pas d'accord, je ne suis pas en conflit avec toi. Nos avis **divergent**.

---

**EDIT**

Après une recherche plus approfondie, le verbe **[Différer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diff%C3%A9rer)** semble mieux convenir dans ce cas.

> Avoir une attitude ou un avis opposés sur quelque chose. *Différer d'opinion* (Ac. 1835-1932). *Une mémoire à propos de laquelle nous différerons toujours d'avis* (Verlaine, Œuvres compl.,t. 4, Mém. veuf, 1886, p. 292).

Toujours avec l'exemple donné, on obtient donc :

> Bien que nous ne soyons pas d'accord, je ne suis pas en conflit avec toi. Nos avis **diffèrent**

Comment: Je crois que le mot est bien choisin, mais à partir de cette définition il est peu facile de voir en quoi « diverger » diminuerait le conflit. Même si le TLF ne donne la suivante que pour des « inanimés concrets », je trouve que le sens figuratif qu'on souhaite ici se base plutôt sur elle : « S'écarter de plus en plus l'un de l'autre, à partir d'un point commun ou voisin. » Selon cette acception on est sur deux voies différentes, on ne saurait être d'accord sur ce qu'on n'a pas en commun.

Comment: Le sens de "diverger" proposé dans la réponse diminue le conflit du fait que l'on exprime pas son désaccord directement mais que l'on annonce avoir un autre opinion sans critiquer celle de son interlocuteur. Le sens « S'écarter de plus en plus l'un de l'autre, à partir d'un point commun ou voisin. » n'est valide que pour des objets, ce qui ne convient pas à ce cas de figure.

Comment: C'est vrai, mais ce n'est néanmoins pas le sens « être en désaccord, en opposition » qui permet cette expression indirecte du désaccord ! ;) Il n'est pas facile de repérer tous les sens figuratifs d'un terme, alors je dirais qu'il y a une petite lacune dans l'article du TLF vis-à-vis du sens qu'on veut sans doute ici.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec cette remarque, mais je n'ai malheureusement pas trouvé meilleure source à citer. Ce n'est pas le sens le plus en accord avec ce qui est recherché.

Comment: J'ai édité ma réponse, je pense que cette définition correspond mieux à ce qui est demandé.

Comment: En fait ma question ne portait pas vraiment sur le meilleur mot pour qualifier deux avis différents, mais plutôt sur la possibilité d'utiliser le mot "orthogonal" en français. J'utilise moi-même l'expression "nos avis diffèrent" dans ce cas.